# ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor - Too many automatic redirections were attempted exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, recaptcha

Following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/using-a-catpcha-to-prevent-automated-programs-%28bots%29-from-using-your-aspnet-web-site) I implemented recaptcha on a website. After attempting to submit the form I get the below exception on Line 37. This error does not happen if I remove the recaptcha code on LIne 37.

```
Line 35:     if (IsPost && Validation.IsValid())
Line 36:     {
**Line 37:         if (ReCaptcha.Validate())**
Line 38:         {


[WebException: Too many automatic redirections were attempted.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6120419
   Microsoft.Web.Helpers.ReCaptcha.ExecuteValidateRequest(String formData) +194
   Microsoft.Web.Helpers.ReCaptcha.Validate(HttpContextBase context, String privateKey, VirtualPathUtilityBase virtualPathUtility) +131
   Microsoft.Web.Helpers.ReCaptcha.Validate(String privateKey) +98
   ASP._Page_conference_Default_cshtml.Execute() in 
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +208
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors) +68
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +123
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +19
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +67
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext) +121
```

Comment: What does `ReCaptcha.Validate()` do?  Is it redirecting the user somewhere?

Comment: if validate is true then i take 6 HTML form fields (text boxes) from the request, store them in a variable, insert them into a database table, and Response.Redirect to a confirmation page.

Comment: But does `Validate()` *itself* perform a redirect?  Is that redirect causing a loop in the requests?  Or, when you perform your redirect, are you then running `Validate()` again on the resulting page?  Somewhere you've created a loop of redirects, either one page which redirects to itself indefinitely or multiple pages which redirect to each other indefinitely.

Comment: `Validate()` just returns a bool and then within that code block I called Response.Redirect. On the confirmation page that the redirect takes you to I just say "Thanks!" in a `<p>` tag. Am I understanding your question? Thanks.

Comment: You may want to debug the code and see which code is doing the redirect and where.